# Prevent user from entering the same number twice in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to make a lottery game in C# for a school project but i can't seem to find any useful information on how to prevent a user from typing in a number twice. The book we are using doesn't help much either as there is no such information about this writen there.

Bare with me here, as i'm new to coding and still learning. My code works fine, but the user can type in for example 10 1's and the random generated numbers can randomize the same numbers twice as well.

Any help appreciated!

```
Random number = new Random();
int[] numbers = new int[10];
int[] userInput = new int[10];

Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the lottery! Enter 10 numbers between 1 and 25!");

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) {
  numbers[i] = number.Next(0, 26);
}

for (int i = 0; i < userInput.Length; i++) {
  Console.Write("Enter number {0}: ", i + 1);
  userInput[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

  if (userInput[i] < 1) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error, number to low. Try again!");
    i--;
  }
  if (userInput[i] > 25) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error, number to high. Try again!");
    i--;
  }

}

Console.Clear();

Console.WriteLine("The results are in! Drumroll please..");
Console.WriteLine("Pssst... press any key to see the results!");

Console.ReadKey();

Array.Sort(numbers);
Array.Sort(userInput);

foreach(var userNumber in userInput) {
  foreach(var randomNumber in numbers) {
    if (userNumber == randomNumber) {
      Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
      Console.WriteLine("{0} is a match with the lottery number: {1}!", userNumber, randomNumber);
    }
  }
}

Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing this awesome lottery game! To bad there is no price..");
Console.WriteLine("If you enjoyed this game, you can always play it again!");
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Well, you would need to check if the number entered is already present in the numbers entered previously.

Comment: Yes, i am aware of that but i'm not sure how to do that im afraid

Comment: @J... Yeah that would help. This is a distance course though and the teachers aren't that helpful to be honest. They are just telling us to Google and use the books. So that's why im trying to reach out here for help. I can use the comparison operator but im not sure how to compare the input of the user and the data in the array to prevent the program to store the already used number in the userInput array

Comment: Maybe you don't need to search how to prevent a user from inputting a number twice, but how to check if a number is in an array.

Comment: @Emaro Yes, and i want to write out a message if the input of the user is already stored in the array. That is where i have problems. I know how to use arrays and how to compare two arrays and look for similarities

Comment: @J... Thanks for the tip. I will check out methods at the array page

Comment: There is a but in number.Next(0, 26); This will generate numbers from 0 to 25. The lower bound is inclusive, whilst the upper bound is exclusive. So you could generate a 0 value, which the user is not allowed to enter later

Comment: @treze Thank you for that information! I will edit number.Next to number.Next(1, 26)

Comment: Bug, not but...typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `HashSet` instead of an array. A `HashSet` is a special collection, that does not allow the insertion of duplicate values.

```
const int Count = 10;
const int LowerBound = 1;
const int UpperBound = 25;
var number = new Random();
var numbers = new HashSet<int>(Count);
var userInput = new HashSet<int>(Count);

Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the lottery! Enter {0} numbers between {1} and {2}!", Count, LowerBound, UpperBound);

// we generate numbers until we have 10 unique
while (numbers.Count < Count)
{
    numbers.Add(number.Next(LowerBound, UpperBound + 1)); // duplicate numbers will not be added
}

// ask for user input until we have 10 unique numbers 
while (userInput.Count < Count)
{
    Console.Write("Enter number {0}: ", userInput.Count + 1);
    var input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (input < LowerBound)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error, number too low. Try again!");
    }
    else if (input > UpperBound)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error, number too high. Try again!");
    }
    else if (!userInput.Add(input)) // returns false if the value was already added
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error, number already entered. Try again!");
    }
}

Console.Clear();

Console.WriteLine("The results are in! Drumroll please..");
Console.WriteLine("Pssst... press any key to see the results!");

Console.ReadKey();

foreach (var userNumber in userInput.OrderBy(x => x))
{
    if (numbers.Contains(userNumber))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is a match with the lottery number: {0}!", userNumber);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing this awesome lottery game! To bad there is no price..");
Console.WriteLine("If you enjoyed this game, you can always play it again!");
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works fine for this purpose. I will look into this and read more about HashSet! Much appreciated!